# How to determine difference in month between rows in a way like crossing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a report where I need to calculate the difference between two dates in different rows in a way like cross to cross. How can I achieve this result with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Customers (
  customerid INT,
  issuedate DATE,
  statusdate date
)

INSERT INTO #Customers
SELECT 928, '2017-07-24',   '2018-01-22'
union
SELECT 928, '2018-04-05',   '2018-10-05'
union
SELECT 928, '2019-02-21',   '2019-01-21'

--The Result should be like this "Displaying the difference between '2018-01-22' and '2018-04-05'
--And difference between '2018-20-05' and '2019-02-21'

DROP TABLE #Customers
```

I expect the result from the query to display the difference in months between columns 'statusdate' and 'issuedate' giving an output of 
`3` and 
`4`

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2018-01-22','2018-04-05')
UNION
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,'2018-10-05','2019-02-21')
```

Comment: That's what those queries would return. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LAG()` function to get the value from the previous row, and check where that value is not null. We use a sub-select to fetch the values, as the `LAG()` functions cannot be used in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, T.PreviousStatusDate, T.issuedate) as difference
FROM (
  SELECT LAG(c.statusdate) OVER(ORDER BY c.statusdate) as PreviousStatusDate,
         c.issuedate
  FROM Customers c
) AS T
WHERE T.PreviousStatusDate IS NOT NULL
```

Result,

```
difference
----------------
3
4
```

- See live demo at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d1169/10

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and you want to get the difference between values from current and subsequent rows, next approach using [LEAD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) may help:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH, statusdate, nextissuedate) AS [Difference]
FROM (
   SELECT 
      customerid,
      issuedate,
      statusdate,
      LEAD(issuedate) OVER (PARTITION BY customerid ORDER BY issuedate) AS nextissuedate
   FROM #Customers     
) t
WHERE nextissuedate IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
----------------
Difference
----------------
3
4
```